# ASP.net and WCF some clarification on "overriding"

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Recently I  faced few interview questions.The interviewer asked the to give the detailed answer.

1)Can we override a WCF service (Its is not OOPS overriding) ?.Explain the reason on either end. (WCF Related).

2)Can we override Page events (Page_Load())?.Explain reason.(ASP.NET related).

3)What is the primary responsibility of Pre_Init( page) event ,apart from user preference 
setting,skinning?

4) Can we override  Static methods.Explain the reason.(C# related)

can anyone help me to understand the reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't really override WCF service operations. If your Service Contract class has two Service Operation methods with the same name but different parameters (i.e. legitimate C# overloads), WCF will throw an `InvalidOperationException` when the service is started. If you really want to do this, you can change the exposed operation name of one of the methods in the `OperationContract` attribute:

   ```
   [OperationContract(Name = "GetDataWithString")]
   public string GetData(string input)
   {
      ...
   }

   [OperationContract(Name = "GetDataWithNumber")]
   public string GetData(int input)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```
2. You *can* override Page events in ASP.Net; this is pretty widely used and usually pretty crucial. You can either explicitly override the methods from the `Page` class your custom page inherits from, or you can name your methods in such a way that ASP.Net knows that they're to be treated as overrides. For example, declaring a method in a page's code-behind with the signature below will automatically override the Page_Init method.

   ```
   void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
   ```
3. The `Page_Init` method is where ASP.Net starts tracking ViewState. This means that anything done to any of the page's controls is now marked as Dirty in the ViewState `StateBag`, and so will be base-64 encoded and sent down to the client in the ViewState hidden input field, and therefore sent back to the server on a postback. Changing controls' values before ViewState is being tracked will help stop ViewState getting too large. See [this seminal article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/truly-understanding-viewstate.aspx) for more details.
4. Only class instance methods can be marked as `virtual`, as the compiler-created [v-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) is attached to class instances. Static class members are not attached to instances but to the class itself, therefore there's no way to override them. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-override-static-methods.aspx) explains this in more detail, and gives some workarounds.